# Copy Specific Dataset Columns to Datatable

Tags: c#, xslt, datatable, dataset

i have a DataSet which reads xml data and it has almost 20 columns,
i need 5 columns from the DataSet .
i have tried at my level but not able to get the DataTable with the specific columns i need.
some codes which i tried are :

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();  //dt is blank DataTable 
DataSet ds = new DataSet();  //ds is existing DataSet which has single table in it
dt.Columns[0]=dst4.Tables[0].Columns[0];               
dt.Columns.Add(dst4.Tables[0].Columns[0]);  
ds.Tables.Add(dt)
dst4.Tables.Columns.Add(dt);
```

Comment: Which columns do you want? You say 5 but which, your code does not show it.

Answer (score 1):

You could clone the table which creates an empty table with the same columns, then you can remove the redundant columns.Here is an example with named columns, you could also use the indices:

```
DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0].Clone();
var colToTake = new[] { "Col1", "Col3", "Col7", "Col15", "Col19" };
var colsToRemove = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
    .Where(c => !colToTake.Contains(c.ColumnName));
foreach (DataColumn colToRemove in colsToRemove)
    dt.Columns.Remove(colToRemove);
```

Comment: i tried another way to accomplish task by removong unwanted columns from dataset .
    ds.Tables[0].Columns.Remove("column1");

Comment: @codemirror: You confuse me. Why do you remove columns from the original tables instead of the empty cloned table? That's not what you have mentioned in your question. And i'm also missing if it works.

Comment: sorry , let me tell , i have to show the dataset on to the datagridview, this is the only use of dataset , that's why i removed specific unwanted columns from dataset and now can bind it to datagridview.

Comment: @codemirror: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208186/how-do-i-display-only-certain-columns-from-a-data-table

Answer (score 0):

say you have to copy columns "ColumnName1", "ColumnName2", "ColumnName3", "ColumnName4", "ColumnName5" to new `DataTable`

```
DataTable source = dst4.Tables[0];
DataTable dt = source.DefaultView.ToTable(false, "ColumnName1", "ColumnName2", "ColumnName3", "ColumnName4", "ColumnName5");
```